# Impedance problem on MCU ADC input line

Tags: microcontroller, adc, offset

I am working with an EFM8UB10 20QFN 8bit MCU from Silicon Labs, using the 10-bit ADC feature.

Due to a change in the PCB design, the trace to the ADCin port (P0.7) has increased about 20x in length (cannot change PCB anymore.)

Since the change, I see the SAR 10 bit offset error has changed, from -1 to -1.3 LSB to about -1.8 to -2.0 LSB.

I already have a 0.01uF capacitor attached to the P0.7 line.

I wonder if there are any ways I can compensate offset error using passive components or in any other way.

[Datasheet](https://www.mouser.sg/ProductDetail/Silicon-Labs/EFM8UB10F8G-C-QFN20?qs=h6RIvS%252BzmlcbFT94aBUCAg%3D%3D)

Comment: Why do you need to compensate for it using any components? Compensate in software. The software should acquire the zero offset and then subtract it from the rest of the readings. If you’re so concerned about 1LSB offset error change, wait until you see how bad the gain error is over a 20C temperature range. If you didn’t design to minimize it, it’ll make the offset error inconsequential. It’ll be 1-2 orders of magnitude worse at full scale.

Comment: This is a change of ~0.1%, is it really significant compared to what you're measuring?

Comment: Are you certain this is solely because of trace length and not because the trace is now picking up noise from somewhere? Either radiated noise as it now acts as an antenna,  or conducted noise as it now goes near misc other stuff on your PCB.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've introduced an offset due to layout, specifically voltage drop across traces. Depending on what you are using as a reference, that drop could be as low as 1.7mV/LSB.

I presume you're worried about this because you don't get a measurable change until the input voltage rises above the first bit transition. Otherwise you'd just add a small amount to the ADC output digitally.

You might be able to reduce it to an acceptable amount by adding a jumper if you know where the current is flowing. Try poking around the "grounds" with a multimeter on a low range (eg. 199.9mV FS).